# Gridview with vertical scrollbar

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview with 10 columns, I need to enter data manually in the gridview.
I want a vertical scroll bar for the gridview, but it should start from the 2nd column of the gridview. the 1st column consist of id which i need to view while entering data. So can we have the 1st column stable, and the other should scroll.?
please help.

Comment: Can you please clarify, whether you want vertical scrollbar or horizontal? I think, it should be horizontal.

Comment: Check http://www.bluelemoncode.com/post/2011/12/30/Freezing-gridview-header-and-columns-while-scrolling-rest-of-the-content.aspx

Comment: yes, sorry , it is horizontal .